# JavaScript override class method conditionally

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a class that I have defined that I use all over my application.  I have one page where I would like to change override some of the methods on all instances of the class.  Here is some code to illustrate.

myclass-script.js

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    foo: function() {
        return 1;
    },

    bar: function() {
        return this.foo() + 9;
    },
});
```

change-myclass-script.js

```
MyClass.implement({
    foo: function() {
        return this.parent() * -1;
    },
});
```

If I include on a page myclass-script.js I should see:

```
var test = new MyClass();
test.bar() === 10; //true
```

If I include myclass-script.js and then change-myclass-script.js I should see:

```
var test = new MyClass();
test.bar() === 8; //true
```

The issue I am having is that MyClass.implement applies to all instances of MyClass but it doesn't "override" the method, it replaces it.  So the this.parent() call fails because there is no parent for that method.  If I do MyClass.extend it does not apply like I want and I do not see the instances of MyClass calling the overridden method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could store the old version of foo, basically what Dimitar does:

```
var foo = MyClass.prototype.foo;
MyClass.implement('foo', function(){
    return foo.call(this) * -1;
});
```

Or you can use [Class.Refactor](http://www.mootools.net/docs/more/Class/Class.Refactor) from MooTools More with the `previous` method:

```
Class.refactor(MyClass, {
    foo: function(){
        return this.previous() * -1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Class.refactor is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is the best practice but it will allow you to run whatever logic you want or just return original method if not required...

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    foo: function() {
        return 1;
    },
    bar: function() {
        return this.foo() + 9;
    }
});

var f = new MyClass();
console.log(f.bar()); // 10

(function() {
    var orig = MyClass.prototype.foo;
    MyClass.prototype.foo = function() {
        return orig.apply(this, arguments) * -1; 
    };
})();

console.log(f.bar()); // 8
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/cXTrD/7/

Answer (score -1):

Try doing the following:

```
MyClass.prototype.implement({
```

Comment: It applies the function to the class itself instead of object instances of it.

Comment: implement is not a .prototype method, though?

Comment: sorry, i thought "implement" was the name of his method, and overall I was pseudo-coding which probably wasn't very clear